# Template lite - incrementing a variable

Tags: php, template-lite

is it possible in html side increase a variable ?

i mean

`{$i++}` in template lite does not work

What i want is that if i is multiple of four , it must add a `<li></li>`

```
 {foreach from=$books value=book}

 {/foreach}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Template Lite, but [this page](http://templatelite.sourceforge.net/docs/language.functions.custom.html) suggests the `counter` function may do the job.

Comment: Also, a template library that allows you to make database calls? I think that's sort of missing the point of having a template library – separation of concerns.

Comment: I don't see any database accesses.

Comment: i use framework, it automatically connects me to db